# My knapsack code is giving wrong output?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, knapsack-problem

I was trying to write a simple 0-1 knapsack problem but am encountering some error. Help would be appreciated.

```
T = int(input().strip())
def knapsack(n,k,ar):
    if n==0 or k==0:
        return 0
    elif ar[n-1]>k:
        return knapsack(n-1,k,ar)
    else:
        return max(knapsack(n-1,k,ar),ar[n-1] + knapsack(n-1,k-ar[n-1],ar))
for t in range(T):
    a = input().strip()
    n,k = int(a[0]),int(a[2])
    ar = [int(i) for i in input().strip().split(' ')]
    print(knapsack(n,k,ar))
```

I ran this again an input of

```
2
3 12
1 6 9
5 9
3 4 4 4 8
```

and I am receiving wrong output? I cannot find any error. Thanks in advance

Output

```
1
8
```

Answer (score 2):

Your algorithm is fine but your input to the function is wrong.

In the first input, the line `n,k = int(a[0]),int(a[2])` is taking `3` and `1` as an input instead of `3` and `12`.
I guess you should use `list(map(int, input().split()))` instead, and get `a[0]` and `a[1]`.